# SQL query to extract records from each group of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table data is as below:

[image: Table Content]

Output should be as below:

[image: output table data]

Conditons:

1. Extract the first row and last row from each group.
2. If the col4 value is "A" in first row, in that case along with first and last row, extract 2 nd row as well.

Is there way to accomplish this using simple SQL query by using any specific analytical functions in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Some quick questions to help with answering: Does the table have a primary key (and is it just an arbitary ID at the start, or Col1 + Col3)? By 'first', 'second' and 'last', how are they ordered - by the 'col2' time field or by 'col3'? And for a given Col1 value, can you have duplicates in col2 e.g., a second row in the table which also has col1 = 1 and col2 = 10/9/2020 17:11?

Comment: Col1 is the primary key, they are ordered by Col1 asc and Col2 desc, yes for a given Col1 value, we can have duplicates in col2 e.g., a second row in the table which also has col1 = 1 and col2 = 10/9/2020 17:11, thanks a lot for your response and for asking these questions

Comment: I don't think Col1 can be the PK - it has duplicates. @Gordon's answer below is good, but you may want to also include how to determine which row you want to report if you have those duplicated rows (it will just require a tweak of the ORDER BY statements in the windowed functions).

Comment: Thanks seanb, yes Col1 is primary key of some other table, it is not primary key in this result set, here in the input table I am showing result set obtained after doing some joins between different tables.

Comment: It's OK re PK - @Gordon's answer doesn't need it. The duplicates of Col1/Col2 are an potential issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use window functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(col4) over (partition by col1 order by col2) as first_col4,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum_asc = 1 or seqnum_desc = 1 or
      (seqnum_asc = 2 and first_col4 = 'a');
```

The subquery enumerates the rows within each value of `col1` -- both ascending and descending.  It also finds the first value.  The outer query just filters on the rows that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the query,Could you please explain me the working of this query, so that in the future I can think in this direction.